# I removed a path from .profile and .bashrc but still present in $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, path, environment-variables

I removed from .profile and .bashrc a path that i added before in $PATH variable but it is still present in this latter. I really don't understand why. Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: Make a quick logout/restart and then respond.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful when i type "logout" i get the error: bash:logout is not a connexion shell: use exit, and when i use exit it redirect to "sh"

Comment: I meant system-level logout, not just exiting the shell. Which distro of linux/unix do you have?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful  ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Ok i rebooted Ubuntu and it works thanks ! but why do i have to reboot ubuntu, i thought rebooting the shell would be enough...

Comment: try loading variable again by following command. source ~/.bashrc  do same for profile

Comment: @mric750 - Because PATH is an environment variable which is a part of  global level configuration. So, you either need to perform a user-logout OR restart for the change to take effect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `source` command.

```
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now check the $PATH.

```
echo $PATH
```

The removed path will not be displayed.

Comment: This won't work if for example my `/etc/profile` sets a `PATH` and `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` only add to it. If this is the case, some trickery is required as demonstrated for example in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/39995/372008).